# Alt key randomly behaves as ctrl when switching workspaces

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces, gnome-shell, workspace-switcher

I'm a heavy user of workspaces and switch between them frequently using shortcuts <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd> such as <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for workspace 1. However at times <kbd>alt</kbd> behaves like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, which switches between the tabs in Chrome.

The desired behaviour of <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd> works 99% of the time, only very rarely it behaves like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>. But it's very annoying for the rest 1% of the time.

Other <kbd>alt</kbd> related shortcuts (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> etc.) work fine.
<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>arrows</kbd> works fine.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with Chrome. I have not observed this issue when focus on programs other than Chrome.

Ubuntu version: 18.04.1 LTS

Edit:
Recently I found that chrome does allow tab switching using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd> (although the [documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179) only says <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd>). So this is likely be a chrome specific conflicting shortcuts issue.